# Intersection between segment and circle with a segment endpoint at center

Tags: geometry, circles

I have a line segment with known endpoints, and one of the endpoints of the line segment is the center of a circle. The circle has a known radius R. How should I find the intersection between the line segment and the circle?

review edit

[image]

Comment: Btw, I'm not like a geometry expert. If someone could just provide me an equation, with the center as (cx, cy) and the endpoint as (dx, dy), it would be great.

Comment: Imagine and draw  a sketch at first. Equations come next.

Comment: Oh I have actually. I just don't know how to take a screenshot on desmos.

Comment: Why the downvote? I just want to know so that I can improve my question next time.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the ray from $(cx,xy)$ through $(dx,dy)$, and let $C$ be the circle centered at $(cx,xy)$ with radius $r$.

A general point on the ray $R$ can be expressed as  $(x,y)$, where
$$
\begin{cases}
x=cx+t(dx-cx)\\[4pt]
y=cy+t(dy-cy)\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
where the parameter $t$ can be any nonnegative real number.

Using the distance formula, if $(x,y)$ is the point where $R$ intersects $C$, then
$$\Bigl(\bigl(cx+t(dx-cx)\bigr)- cx\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(\bigl(cy+t(dy-cy)\bigr) - cy\Bigr)^2=r^2$$
Solving for $t$, with the restriction $t\ge 0$, yields
$$t=\frac{r}{\sqrt{(dx-cx)^2+(dy-cy)^2}}$$
To get the corresponding point $(x,y)$, substitute the above result for $t$ in the parametric equations for $x,y$.

Comment: Thank You! This is very helpful

Comment: Also, what part of math does this come under? I'm a freshman in high school and we are doing Geometry right now.

Comment: algebra/precalculus